# AWS S3 filtered replication not triggered after tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I have an S3 replication rule between 2 buckets that's conditional on presence of specific tag (replicate=yes).

If I upload file with a tag it works correctly - object immediately gets into PENDING replication state then COMPLETED after a while.

If I upload without a tag and then set the tag later, no replication is triggered. There's no replication status on the object.

Is it possible to make it work?

For some background: the idea is to have a lambda function tag files as ready for replication based on some future condition/external logic.

I can make it work if instead of tagging I make replication conditional on prefix and then do rename in lambda but my files could be arbitrarily large (think hundreds of GBs) and S3 rename is really a copy+delete while a copy of such large file could potentially time out the lambda since execution time is limited to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it's not going to be possible natively without a workaround (whether that would be a Lambda or something else).
Your use case is actually specifically mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-troubleshoot.html).

> Suppose that in the replication configuration, you add a rule to
> replicate a subset of objects having a specific tag. In this case, you
> must assign the specific tag key and value at the time of creating the
> object for Amazon S3 to replicate the object. If you first create an
> object and then add the tag to the existing object, Amazon S3 does not
> replicate the object.

I think that this behaviour is about to be expected based on the fact that in case you set up a replication to a bucket which already has some objects in it, those "old" objects are not going to be replicated. Only newly uploaded objects are replicated by default and if you want to replicate existing ones, you need to resort to other measures like [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/trigger-cross-region-replication-of-pre-existing-objects-using-amazon-s3-inventory-amazon-emr-and-amazon-athena/) and [2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/).

Comment: I think "Replicate existing objects" from your link nr 2 will only happen once at the time of rule creation and not on ongoing basis, correct?

Comment: As for link 1 - copying over itself is problematic since the files are huge and lambda would time out (which incidentally is the very reason I'm trying to use replication)

Comment: On the first comment with regard to link 2, in their case where they replicate the entire bucket that's my understanding too. As you'll have existing objects at the time of the replication rule creation - anything added later would be considered a new object and replicated either way.

Comment: That wouldn't help in the scenario where tags are assigned later. Looks like there's no good workaround here and the original solution needs to be redesigned.